# Why does the system display this printer twice after I removed it?

Tags: gnome, printing

I had CUPs installed, but just cleaned it from my system.

I deleted all the printers from the Gnome panel.

Yet when I ask to select a printer, there are two queues/connections to the same physical printer (I have only one printer at home). Only the first queue/connection will print anything.  The other one just sends the job to la-la land without complaint or notification.

How does my system even know about this printer after I purged CUPS from my system and deleted the remaining queues from Gnome panel, and why does it show two connections to it?

Also, what is that printer named "print" whose status is rejecting jobs? Where did it find that?

[image]

Comment: For me, one of them does not work as you described it (la-la land, brilliant), while the other one works, but it loads the computer's processor to the max and spins the fan like crazy for about a minute or more before printing. :(

Answer (score 4):

I have that exact same problem -- exactly as you show it in the screenshot.  I have not attempted to delete/purge cups.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (minimal installation) I set up a brand new (out of the box) HP laserjet, got it up and running, and booted up my PC.  And the printer was right there where I expected it to be. However I couldn't print a test page ("file corrupted" says the printer). A little investigation showed that the printer actually worked (I could print up docs with no problem.) Then I noticed the duplicate printer entries (I have only one printer) and I noticed the odd "print" printer that was "rejecting jobs."

I spend a couple of hours trying to figure it out, and didn't find any answers that I understood or thought would work.

But I did notice that when I switched OS to Ubuntu 19.x, that version of Ubuntu didn't exhibit the problem (it worked perfectly).  So that's my answer:

*switch to Ubuntu 19.x ("disco dingo.")*

(I also have been wondering why Libreoffice Ubuntu 18.04 LTS can't access docs on a shared drive unless I mount the drive locally, but that's another question.)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and have the same problem. When I clicked the Brother printer **without** the underscores, the program hang and the network printer did not respond anymore, not even to another (Windows) system. I rebooted the printer to get it responsive again.

Answer (score 4):

For what I've found so far, this isn't an Ubuntu issue, but Gnome problem.
I've tested Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu MATE 20.04, Linux Mint 20.1, Kubuntu 20.04 and guess what... All distros using Gnome, have exactly the same issue.
On Kubuntu, or better saying, with KDE this does not happen.

This is a very old issue and it seems that the Gnome guys doesn't care about this "duplicated printers"...

Comment: But according to wikipedia, [the Cinnamon desktop (of Mint) was totally separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)#History) from Gnome in 2013. Is this bug so old that Cinnamon still has it from the pre-fork days?

Comment: It seems that is indeed an old issue!
btw, "Cinnamon is still built on GNOME technologies". I even dare to say that current Cinnamon version is more close to a current Gnome fork.
I've tested this distros because of this problem in particular and I've found that all Gnome "based" or whatever we can call it, keeps using the old "system-config-printer" (from Red Hat), which is the same as saying Gnome. I don't believe that in all the process of creating an independent DE, the guys from Mint only kept "system-config-printer"... :/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that you did not purge the `cups` package completely, if you are still getting printers to display in any Print dialog, or even the Print.

Check:

1. `systemctl status cups` or `service cups status` .
2. `ls /etc/cups/*`
3. `dpkg -l | grep cups`

CUPS is the current de-facto printing server for linux. I only know of one other method of physically printing from linux, which is with sending postscript files with `lpr` directly to printers. The only other option is sending your files with another file transferring method (email, copy to ftp etc.) to some remote server, with a connected remote printer with WAN connection, that essentially polls for new files in specific server path, and responds to printing requests sent through unconventional means, but with predetermined form and syntax and prints them out accordingly at some remote location.